# How do I add headers for the output csv for apache beam dataflow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I noticed in the java SDK, there is a function that allows you to write the headers of a csv file.
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/TextIO.Write.html#withHeader-java.lang.String-

Is this feature mirrored on the python SDK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can now write to a text and specify a header using the text sink.

**From the documentation:**

```
class apache_beam.io.textio.WriteToText(
    file_path_prefix, file_name_suffix='',
    append_trailing_newlines=True, num_shards=0, 
    shard_name_template=None, coder=ToStringCoder, 
    compression_type='auto', header=None)
```

So you can use the following piece of code:

```
beam.io.WriteToText(bucket_name, file_name_suffix='.csv', 
    header='colname1, colname2')
```

The complete documentation is available here if you want details or check how it is implemented: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.0.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/textio.html#WriteToText

Answer (score 1):

This is not implemented at this moment. However you can implement/extend it yourself (see [attached notebook](https://gist.github.com/Fematich/97703910d867f972e9d01b21d8f41221) for an example+test with my version of apache_beam).

This is based on a [note in the docstring](https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/python-sdk/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/fileio.py) of the superclass `FileSink`, mentioning that you should overwrite the `open` function:

The new class that works for my version of apache_beam ('0.3.0-incubating.dev'):

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import TextFileSink
from apache_beam.io.fileio import ChannelFactory,CompressionTypes
from apache_beam import coders


class TextFileSinkWithHeader(TextFileSink):
    def __init__(self,
               file_path_prefix,
               file_name_suffix='',
               append_trailing_newlines=True,
               num_shards=0,
               shard_name_template=None,
               coder=coders.ToStringCoder(),
               compression_type=CompressionTypes.NO_COMPRESSION,
               header=None):
        super(TextFileSinkWithHeader, self).__init__(
            file_path_prefix,
            file_name_suffix=file_name_suffix,
            num_shards=num_shards,
            shard_name_template=shard_name_template,
            coder=coder,

            compression_type=compression_type,
            append_trailing_newlines=append_trailing_newlines)
        self.header = header

    def open(self, temp_path):
        channel_factory = ChannelFactory.open(
            temp_path,
            'wb',
            mime_type=self.mime_type)
        channel_factory.write(self.header+"\n")
        return channel_factory
```

You can subsequently use it as follows:

```
beam.io.Write(TextFileSinkWithHeader('./names_w_headers',header="names"))
```

See [the notebook](https://gist.github.com/Fematich/97703910d867f972e9d01b21d8f41221) for the complete overview.

Answer (score 0):

This feature does not yet exist in the Python SDK

Answer (score 0):

For the Python SDK:

```
beam.io.Write(beam.io.WriteToText(
                     file_path_prefix=os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR),
                     file_name_suffix='.csv', header='colname1, colname2')
              )
```