# Write files to GCS using Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataflow

Dataflow is being pre-processed by reading batch data.

The workload is read from Google Cloud Storage (GCS) to process Dataflow and upload it back to GCS.

But after processing the data, I checked the GCS.

result-001.csv

result-002.csv

result-003.csv

This is how the data is divided and stored.
Can't I combine these files into one?

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import apache_beam as beam
import csv
import json
import os
import re
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import parse_table_schema_from_json

def preprocessing(fields):
    fields = fields.split(",")
    header = "label"
    for i in range(0, 784):
        header += (",pixel" + str(i))
    label_list_str = "["
    label_list = []
    for i in range(0,10) :
        if fields[0] == str(i) :
            label_list_str+=str(i)
        else :
            label_list_str+=("0")
        if i!=9 :
            label_list_str+=","
    label_list_str+="],"
    for i in range(1,len(fields)) :
        label_list_str+=fields[i]
        if i!=len(fields)-1:
            label_list_str+=","
    yield label_list_str


def run(project, bucket, dataset) :
        argv = [
            "--project={0}".format(project),
            "--job_name=kaggle-dataflow",
            "--save_main_session",
            "--region=asia-northeast1",
            "--staging_location=gs://{0}/kaggle-bucket-v1/".format(bucket),
            "--temp_location=gs://{0}/kaggle-bucket-v1/".format(bucket),
            "--max_num_workers=8",
            "--worker_region=asia-northeast3",
            "--worker_disk_type=compute.googleapis.com/projects//zones//diskTypes/pd-ssd",
            "--autoscaling_algorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED",
            "--runner=DataflowRunner",
            "--worker_region=asia-northeast3"
        ]

        result_output = 'gs://kaggle-bucket-v1/result/result.csv'
        filename = "gs://{}/train.csv".format(bucket)
        pipeline = beam.Pipeline(argv=argv)
        ptransform = (pipeline
                      | "Read from GCS" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(filename)
                      | "Kaggle data pre-processing" >> beam.FlatMap(preprocessing)
                      )
   
  
    (ptransform
    | "events:out" >> beam.io.WriteToText(
            result_output
        )
     )
    
    pipeline.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run pipeline on the cloud")
    parser.add_argument("--project", dest="project", help="Unique project ID", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--bucket", dest="bucket", help="Bucket where your data were ingested", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--dataset", dest="dataset", help="BigQuery dataset")

    args = vars(parser.parse_args())

    print("Correcting timestamps and writing to BigQuery dataset {}".format(args["dataset"]))

    run(project=args["project"], bucket=args["bucket"], dataset=args["dataset"])
```

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method [beam.io.WriteToText](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.2.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.WriteToText) automatically splits files when writing for best performance. You can explicitly add parameter `num_shards = 1` if you want 1 file only.

> num_shards (int) – The number of files (shards) used for output. If
> not set, the service will decide on the optimal number of shards.
> Constraining the number of shards is likely to reduce the performance
> of a pipeline. Setting this value is not recommended unless you
> require a specific number of output files.

Your writing to text should look like this:

```
(ptransform
    | "events:out" >> beam.io.WriteToText(
            result_output,num_shards=1
        )
     )
```

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question.
When I write a file to Google Cloud Storage, I can still specify the file name: e.g) result.csv
It says result-001.csv.
Is it difficult to write directly to the designated file?

Comment: @꽥꽥꽥 the behavior of the method `WriteToText` is to split the output to shards. If you  really want your output to be result.csv, you can rename the output after writing the file to GCS. You can try checking [this method](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.2.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem.GCSFileSystem.rename) if you are interested in doing that.

Comment: Thank you.
I'll check.
By the way, I would like to make a CSV file with dataflow, is there any way to upload output to GCS including the header?

Comment: @꽥꽥꽥 Header? Like header of your columns?

Comment: That's right.
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3
data1, data2, data3
It's this form.

Comment: I am trying to do now is to upload a file containing a header to GCS and add data by working with the name of the file. However, it doesn't work well.

Comment: [WriteToText](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.WriteToText) also has a `header` parameter. You can check that one out. I also saw this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624809/how-do-i-add-headers-for-the-output-csv-for-apache-beam-dataflow) but it is in java. Though you can easily implement this in python.

Comment: If you know the cases that were implemented in Python, could you share them?

Comment: It is better to create a new post for your new question since it is no longer related to the original post. That way the community can also contribute.